# Bulk copy and rename files by replacing a pattern

Tags: bash, copy, rename

I have a large number of files which has version-stamp on it, e.g ( Av1.dat, B1v1.dat,.., inZ63v1.dat). I'd like to make a copy AND rename them by just replacing v1-->v2 to get (Av2.dat, B1v2.dat, .., inZ63v2.dat). What is the easiest way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
for file in <list of files> ; do
  cp -- "${file}" "$(echo "${file}" | sed -e 's/v1\.dat/v2\.dat/')"
done
```

Comment: You can replace the command substitution with `"${file/v1.dat/v2.dat}"`

Comment: @andlrc: I though about it too, but in the end I choose my solution because is POSIX compliant, while your one work only in Bash.

Comment: I just found out via ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122605/how-do-i-copy-multiple-files-by-wildcard) that this one-line also works (by mmv): mcp "*v1.txt" "#1v2.txt"